# How to remove special characters like "/xC3" from string in Python while keeping same length of string

Tags: python, encoding, gate

I'm dealing with an analysis of AppStore reviews in Python. I generated positions of sentences that I want to save from a given review e.g. (60:75). I had to do it that way because of strange xml format of my file.

Now when I want to gather them, I figured out due to some encoding problems positions drifted. I found out that the problem occurs with special characters (e.g. some Spanish letters - /xC3).

I would like to get rid of them but sustaining the same letters' positions and lengths of sentences. For example changing "é" to "e".

dropbox.txt - text file with reviews

dropbox.xml - xml file from Gate Developer

StartNode is a position of first character of wanted sentence, EndNode of the last character

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("Output/Reviews/dropbox.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
tree = ET.parse("Output/Reviews/dropbox.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

positions = []

for AnnotationSet in root.findall("AnnotationSet"):
    for Annotation in AnnotationSet:
        positions.append((Annotation.attrib["StartNode"], Annotation.attrib["EndNode"]))
for tuple in positions:
    print data[int(tuple[0]):int(tuple[1])], tuple
```

Example:

The positions in first paragraph are correct but after the second one, they shifted by one place forward.

> Update: There have been one or two updates since I wrote my original
>   review, and these problems still have not been fixed.
>
> Faltan algunas cosas aún por mejorar pero relativamente es buena
>
> Having to go inside a folder and
>   make each individual file offline is a bit cumbersome when I need
>   the entire folder to be off-line.

Answer (score 3):

You're handling it as a bytestring, and some of those characters are represented as two bytes, so when you slice it does so by bytes and that doesn't correspond to the number of characters.

You need to convert your string to a unicode string, like

`reviewunicode = reviewtext.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Thanks, it worked but now it seems that emojis cause next problems as follows:

[...] It's a huge pain when you have to download to the phone 

<here it shifts by one character forward>

Someone just shared pictures with me and it says I have to download the app. [...]